# Change margin on a single landscape page in memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, landscape

I have a document where I use memoir and I want to make a single landscape page with a big table where I need to change the margins for this page only to make the table fit.

I have tried using the functions `\newgeometry{margin=1cm}` and `\restoregeometry` available via the package `geometry`, but I can not make it work with landscape.

Does anyone know how to change the margins to make the table fit in the example below?

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{*}{11.5cm}{1.61803}
\setulmarginsandblock{3.2cm}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[c]
\centering
\footnotesize
    \caption{Big table AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC}
    \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{8cm}p{8cm}}
    \toprule\\
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[1cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `table` environment is a floating environment, which means that its contents will be moved around your document to where they look best. As a result, your landscape command might take effect on a different page to the one your table is on. Try rotating the `tabular` environment using the `\rotatebox` command in the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package.

Comment: Hi ChrisS. As far as I understand you are suggesting to use \rotatebox instead of landscape. Does this help in regards to changing the margins to make the large table fit? If so please elaborate.

Comment: First, your tabular is bigger than the entire page even when rotated.  Using \raisebox and \hspace I was able to create tables which filled the entire page, but not sideways tables (margins were off).

Comment: I discovered another problem.  Floats don't know what page they are on, so if \evensidemargin doesn't equal \oddsidemargin...

Answer (score 1):

I tried some more and found the following solution. It is not perfect since I do not have direct control of the size and location of the text block, but it fits the large table almost where I want it.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{*}{11.5cm}{1.61803}
\setulmarginsandblock{3.2cm}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{floatpag}
    \rotfloatpagestyle{empty} 
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\FloatBarrier
\newpage
\begin{center}
\begin{sidewaystable}[hc]
\footnotesize
    \caption{Big table AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC}
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \begin{tabular}{p{7.6cm}p{7.6cm}p{7.6cm}}
    \toprule\\
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{center}
\FloatBarrier
\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to suggest almost the same thing...well, except that I would use the  `sideways` environment from the [rotating](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package. After the new page your can use the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package to change the page margins with: `\newgeometry{margin=1cm}`. You then restore the default page settings by putting `\restoregeometry` at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the `\oddsidemargin`/`\evensidemargin` problem, `\PFwidth` is calculated as the largest possible width that will fit on both odd and even pages.

I found it easier to emulate `sidewaystable` than use it.  The key is that `\caption` will only work in a `minipage`.

The table will automatically be centered on the page.  No additional `\centering` is required.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{*}{11.5cm}{1.61803}
\setulmarginsandblock{3.2cm}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{floatpag}% \thisfloatpagestyle
\usepackage{graphics}% \rotatebox

\newlength{\PFwidth}% maximum width available
\newlength{\PFx}
\newlength{\PFy}

\newcommand{\PFcalc}% compute PFx, PFy and PFwidth
{\setlength{\PFy}{0.5\paperheight}% compute distance from center of page to center of text
\addtolength{\PFy}{-0.5\textheight}%
\addtolength{\PFy}{-1in}%
\addtolength{\PFy}{-\topmargin}%
\addtolength{\PFy}{-\headheight}%
\addtolength{\PFy}{-\headsep}%
\setlength{\PFx}{1in}% compute distance from left page to text
\setlength{\PFwidth}{\paperwidth}% maximum width
\ifdim\oddsidemargin<\evensidemargin\addtolength{\PFx}{\oddsidemargin}%
  \addtolength{\PFwidth}{\oddsidemargin}%
  \addtolength{\PFwidth}{-\evensidemargin}%
\else\addtolength{\PFx}{\evensidemargin}%
  \addtolength{\PFwidth}{\evensidemargin}%
  \addtolength{\PFwidth}{-\oddsidemargin}%
\fi}

\NewEnviron{pagetable}%
{\PFcalc%
\begin{table}[p]\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}%
\strut\hspace{-\PFx}% left shift
\raisebox{\PFy}[0.5\textheight][0.5\textheight]{%
\parbox[c]{\PFwidth}{\centering\rotatebox{-90}{%
\begin{minipage}{\paperheight}%
\centering\BODY
\end{minipage}}}}\hspace{-\PFwidth}%
\end{table}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{pagetable}
    \footnotesize
    \caption{Big table AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC}
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \begin{tabular}{p{7.6cm}p{7.6cm}p{7.6cm}}
    \toprule\\
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\[2cm]
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{pagetable}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```