# geometry - adjust textwidth to new margins

Tags: margins, geometry, width, border

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,csvsimple}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

[...]

\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
            \csvautobooktabular[]{csvs/large_table.csv}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \caption{\small{Blah blah blah}}
        \label{tab:test}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

The above code will give me something like this:
[image]

which, I guess, is acceptable when reading the file on a digital device because you can zoom in.

But just to be sure, I would like to extend the space available to the table:

[image]

How do I do that? I tried using the `geometry` package

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,csvsimple}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

[...]

\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
            \csvautobooktabular[]{csvs/large_table.csv}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \caption{\small{Blah blah blah}}
        \label{tab:test}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Which had the very interesting (and very useless) effect that the margins were reduced but apparently, the textwidth was not changed to reflect this.

[image]

So I tried

```
\newgeometry{margin=1cm,textwidth=\paperwidth-2cm}
```

Which achieved perfectly nothing.

**UPDATE**

Using

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max width = \dimexpr\paperheight-1cm, center} ... \end{adjustbox}
```

as proposed by Werner in the comments results in

[image]

which would be fine inasfar as width is concerned. Any way to violate the top (left, if you hold it in portrait) margin?

Comment: How about using `\begin{adjustbox}{max width = \dimexpr\paperheight-2cm, center}` ... `\end{adjustbox}`? Since you're working on a landscape page, I'm using `\paperheight` instead of `\paperwidth`.

Comment: You could do something like: `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\adjustbox{scale=1.2}{\csvautobooktabular[]{csvs/large_table.csv}}}`

Comment: Generally it is easier to violate the margins than change them.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196702/change-margin-on-a-single-landscape-page-in-memoir for example.

Comment: @Werner nice ... except I still have a much too large margin at the top (left, if you hold the paper in portrait format) of the page, preventing me from fitting another table onto the same page.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum this doesn't compile (``!Unidentified control sequence``). If I change ``\csvautobooktabular`` to ``\autobooktabular``, I get ``! LaTeX Error: Command \� unavailable in encoding OT1.`` If I try to get a table into it, I get ``! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`` ...

Comment: @JohnKormylo if I try with werner's approach, how do I violate the top (left in portrait) margin?

Comment: You cannot put a `table` in a box, you would have to put a `tabular` or similar in a box. I don't have your csv file, so I cannot make a complete example with your table. I just tried it with some other text in it. However, if `\csvautobooktabular` works in your original example, it should also work with the modified one. The core of the solution is to use `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{Some Contents}, where `Some Contents` is wider than `\textwidth`.

Comment: Negative \vspace* and \hspace* will move something (a minipage for example) up and left (respectively).  Additional negative \hspace on the right (see also \rlap)  will prevent a warning for overfull \hbox.

Comment: I faced very the same issue and what seems to help is changing the order of the newgeometry and landscape commands: i.e., `\newgeometry{margin=1cm} \begin{landscape}`, then the table, and `\end{landscape} \restoregeometry` try this, if it works, I post an answer